# Check box is toggled when I click on any text

Tags: php, html

I am dynamically creating the checkbox input fields with text lables, and trying to create a treeview when I click any item in the tree the first check box is always toggling.What can be the possible reason.

```
if($category->visible==1){
  echo '<div class="categorylist level'.$depth.' cat">';

  $count=$DB->count_records('course',['category'=>$category->id]);

  if($count>0){
    echo '<div class="parent">';
    if($depth>0){
      $indent=10;
       for($i=0;$i<=$depth;$i++){
        $indent=$indent+$depth;
        echo '<div style="margin-left:'.$indent.'px">';
        }
     }
     echo '<input type="checkbox" id="category" name="cat[]" value='.$category->id.'/>';
     echo '<label for="category"'.$category->id.'"><span class="">'.$category->name.' ('.$count.')</span></label><br>';
     if($depth>0){
       for($i=0;$i<=$depth;$i++){
          echo '</div>';
       }
     }
     echo '</div>';

   }
   else{
       echo '<div class="parent">';
       if($depth>0){
         $indent=10;
         for($i=0;$i<=$depth;$i++){
            $indent=$indent+$depth;
            echo '<div style="margin-left:'.$indent.'px">';
         }
        }
        echo '<label for="category"><span class="">'.$category->name.' ('.$count.')</span></label><br>';
        if($depth>0){
          for($i=0;$i<=$depth;$i++){
              echo '</div>';
          }
        }
        echo '</div>';
       }
       echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: this seems to be related to javascript not php, please add your javascript to the question too.

Comment: I have not written any kind of javascript

Comment: ahh, ok can you checked this `<label for="category"'.$category->id.'">` maybe its the issue, label with duplicate for attribute can cause this issue, make sure that you have no label with same `$category->id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked this `<label for="category"'.$category->id.'">` could be your issue, label with duplicate `for` attribute can cause this issue, make sure that you have no label with same `$category->id`